# На сколько функционален новый Swift на Windows?

Tags: java, ios, swift

Друзья, подскажите, стоит ли учиться программировать мобильные приложения для ios в  Swift на Windows, если мака нет. Недавно Apple анонсировала новый выпуск swift для windows. На сколько он функционален и отлажен ? У кого есть опыт ?
https://apptractor.ru/info/news/swift-windows.html

P.S. Есть начальный опыт java: примитивы, объекты, синтаксис, создание простых приложений заказа товара с тремя активностями и т.д. Сложно ли переучиться с java на swift ? (логика, синтаксис, библиотеки/функционал, производительность..) ?

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, у Apple будет все другое, и учить придётся все с нуля, кроме, может быть, английских букв, точки с запятой и скобок. Пока для Windows есть, по сути, только стандартные библиотеки. Чтобы написать приложение для iOS, вам по-прежнему нужен либо живой Mac, либо виртуальный Mac. XCode для Windows по-прежнему нет, если хотите XCode, нужна виртуальная машина. Но учить язык вы можете уже сейчас, если очень хочется.

Answer (score 0):

Mac или хакинтош, если программировать для iOS. Swift на windows - просто очередной язык программирования без "окружения", типа какого нибудь lisp. Язык-игрушка, или "язык для логики", который ещё нужно будет увязать с вводом-выводом как то. Библиотек нет толком под win. Там порт поддерживается одним человеком (см. swift.org.) Кстати точка с запятой в swift - редко используемая штука.) про поддерживаемые платформы читать здесь собственно https://swift.org/platform-support/ а как так сказать swift core язык приятный. Кучу легаси способов наряду с "новыми" способами сделать одно и то же в себе не тянет пока как C++ например делает. Но как минус, хочу сказать, что от версии к версии библиотеки для iOS и Mac зачастую теряется совместимость кода. Но это не в "core", а именно в SDK для iOS и OS X